# Как работать с адресами памяти в C#?

Tags: c#, .net, указатели, .net-core

Есть адрес памяти 0x7C4540, и я хочу записать/получить из него значение. Как мне это сделать в C#?

Comment: Это затруднительно даже в Си/C++ со слабой типизацией (формально к любой памяти обратиться можно, но скорее всего ОС выдаст `Segmentation Fault`), а уж в C# со строгой типизацией и вообще своеобразной работой с памятью...

Comment: @AivanF. в С и С++ нет с этим проблем ) int* ptr = 0xfedcba1

Answer (score 0):

#### Это опасно, но решимо.

Во-первых разрешите "Небезопасный код" в настройках проекта.

Затем создайте функцию помеченную `unsafe`.

Вот пример считывания числа (int32) из памяти:

```
private static unsafe void Test()
{
    var ptr = (int*) 0x7C4540;
    var value = *ptr;

    Console.WriteLine($"Считали число: {value}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для кросс-платформенности вам нужен тип `IntPtr`.
А дальше... `using System.Runtime.InteropServices`

`Marshal.ReadByte`, `Marshal.Readxxx`,  `Marshal.Writexxx`, и другие ф-ции из `Marshal`.

```
IntPtr p = new IntPtr(0xfedcba1);
byte b = Marshal.ReadByte(p); // Может вызвать сбой
Marshal.WriteByte(p,b);// Может вызвать сбой
```

Не смотря на то, что данный метод позволяет обойтись без пометки `unsafe`, при неправильной работе получите Access Violation и другие интересные ошибки, и даже креш VM.